# Right way to inherit interface by interface

Tags: qt, interface, qt-creator, abstract-class, qabstracttablemodel

I have interface `class IHistory`. And i want to implement `QAbstractTableModel`.
My code invoke `undefined reference to vtable` error, and it's doesn't fix by running `qmake`.

**(ihistory.h)**

```
class IHistory: public QAbstractTableModel
{
    ...
    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    virtual QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    ...
};
```

In child class i wrote **(history.h)**:

```
class History : public IHistory
{
    //Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(IHistory)

public:
    History();
    ~History();

    ...
    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    ...
};
```

Is there a right way, or i should implement `QAbstractTableModel` in `class History`?

Answer (score 0):

I found right way!
Just delete redefining in interface, and add implementation of all abstract functions in `history.cpp`.

So, something like rule:

*If you want to inherit in interface class from other interface in QT, just do it like usual: `class IFoo: public IBar`. Then, when you implement interface `IFoo`:*

1) Inherit from interface: *`class Foo: public IFoo`*

2) Press *`Alt + Enter`* and choose *`Insert virtual methods of base classes`*

3) Then, for each methods use *`Alt + Enter`* and choose *`Implement (methodname) in class Foo.cpp`*

4) Profit!